# Flask-WTF: Queries of FormFields in FieldList are none after validate_on_submit

Tags: flask-wtforms

I'm trying to generate dynamic forms using Flask-WTF to create a new product based on some templates. A product will have a list of required key-value pairs based on its type, as well as a list of parts required to build it. The current relevant code looks as follows:

forms.py:

```
class PartSelectionForm(Form):
    selected_part = QuerySelectField('Part', get_label='serial', allow_blank=True)
    part_type = StringField('Type')
    slot = IntegerField('Slot')
    required = BooleanField('Required')

    def __init__(self, csrf_enabled=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PartSelectionForm, self).__init__(csrf_enabled=False, *args, **kwargs)

class NewProductForm(Form):
    serial = StringField('Serial', default='', validators=[DataRequired()])
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes', default='')
    parts = FieldList(FormField(PartSelectionForm))
```

views.py:

```
@app.route('/products/new/<prodmodel>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_product(prodmodel):

    try: 
        model = db.session.query(ProdModel).filter(ProdModel.id==prodmodel).one()
    except NoResultFound, e:
        flash('No products of model type -' + prodmodel + '- found.', 'error')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    keys = db.session.query(ProdTypeTemplate.prod_info_key).filter(ProdTypeTemplate.prod_type_id==model.prod_type_id)\
        .order_by(ProdTypeTemplate.prod_info_key).all()

    parts_needed = db.session.query(ProdModelTemplate).filter(ProdModelTemplate.prod_model_id==prodmodel)\
        .order_by(ProdModelTemplate.part_type_id, ProdModelTemplate.slot).all()  

    class F(forms.NewProductForm):
        pass   

    for key in keys:
        if key.prod_info_key in ['shipped_os','factory_os']:
            setattr(F, key.prod_info_key, forms.QuerySelectField(key.prod_info_key, get_label='version'))
        else:
            setattr(F, key.prod_info_key, forms.StringField(key.prod_info_key, validators=[forms.DataRequired()]))

    form = F(request.form)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        for part in parts_needed:
            entry = form.parts.append_entry(forms.PartSelectionForm())
            entry.part_type.data=part.part_type_id
            entry.slot.data=slot=part.slot
            entry.required.data=part.required
            entry.selected_part.query = db.session.query(Part).join(PartModel).filter(PartModel.part_type_id==part.part_type_id, Part.status=='inventory')

    if form.__contains__('shipped_os'):
        form.shipped_os.query = db.session.query(OSVersion).order_by(OSVersion.version)
    if form.__contains__('factory_os'):
        form.factory_os.query = db.session.query(OSVersion).order_by(OSVersion.version)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ...
```

Everything works as expected on a GET request, but on the validate_on_submit I get errors. The error is that all of the queries and query_factories for the `selected_part` `QuerySelectField`s in the list of `PartSelectionForms` is none, causing either direct errors in WTForms validation code or when Jinja2 attempts to re-render the `QuerySelectField`s. I'm not sure why this happens on the POST when everything appears to be correct for the GET.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that although I set the required queries on a GET I'm not doing it for any `PartSelectionForm` `selected_part` entries on the POST. Since I already intended `part_type`, `slot`, and `required` to be hidden form fields, I added the following immediately before the `validate_on_submit` and everything works correctly:

```
for entry in form.parts: 
    entry.selected_part.query = db.session.query(Part).join(PartModel).\
    filter(PartModel.part_type_id==entry.part_type.data, Part.status=='inventory')
```